# Spine.js Fetch Custom Records

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I have a `spine.js` application where I am trying to fetch a list of `users` who recently commented on the site.  My server path is `/users/recently_commented`.

I tried creating a class method:

Spine.js Video Model

```
class App.User extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'User', 'name'
  @extend Spine.Model.Ajax

  @recentlyCommented: ->
    $.get @url("recently_commented")
```

When I pass `User.recentlyCommented` to my view it returns `undefined`.

How would I fetch those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some problems with how you're calling [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

First of all, `$.get` is asynchronous so `User.recentlyCommented` will return a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) rather than a list of User instances.

Secondly, you should be calling `$.get` with a callback function of some sort to process the `recently_commented` data when it arrives:

```
$.get @url('recently_commented'), (data) ->
    # Now convert 'data' to User model instances,
    # if this function cares about its context then
    # you'll probably want to use => to define it.
```

Your view will also need to listen for "new model" created events somehow as the Users won't exist until some time after `$.get` (and thus `recentlyCommented`) returns.

Sorry but I don't know Spine so I don't know what the idiomatic approach is here.